# Why are these strings padded every other byte?

Tags: disassembly, windows, executable

I've seen this multiple times, through various apps and snooping of hex values. Character strings but every other value is actually a null byte. This particular example is with API Monitor, but I'm almost positive I've seen it through hexdumps of Windows or DOS executables.

[image: CreateFileW]
[image: Raw data]

My first thought might be Unicode or some other sort of wide character standard. But Unicode formats (especially Uni16) are variable width.

Comment: No. In Windows "Unicode" refers to a fixed-with character type where every characters has 16 bits (2 bytes). Win32 API methods that end with a `W` (like `CreateFileW`) usually require those strings. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/char-wchar-t-char16-t-char32-t

Comment: @Robert sorry, but that's only half the truth. Unicode is supposed to be a universal character set with _encodings_ and previously Windows used UCS-2 (each code point encoded by _exactly_ one 16-bit code unit) and now uses UTF-16 (usually Little Endian, due to supported machines) since XP. UTF-16 has limitations and IIRC is not capable of expressing every possible code point Unicode has to offer these days. As pointed out UTF-16 _knows_ surrogates and is thus indeed variable-length for each code point. However, because the string only contains ASCII each code point is 16-bit only.

Comment: Welcome to RE.SE, Katastic Voyage: despite some lacking details, Robert is right. This is UTF-16 if encountered on Windows XP or newer or UCS-2 on older Windows versions. The main issue with the comment is that `wchar_t` (= 16-bit type when targeting Windows, 32-bit on every other target platform I know) is merely the *code unit*. Code units are the machine-level "cells" into which the *code points* for Unicode-defined characters are encoded. In UTF-8 the code unit is usually `char`, in UTF-16 (on Windows) `wchar_t` on other systems UTF-32 `wchar_t`. Due to this, ...

Comment: ... "escape routes" exist that enable us to encode *code points* (often referred to as "characters") that go beyond the value range of the underlying *code unit* to be encoded into *multiple code units*. These are then called surrogates. Reserved *code points* exist to "announce" these surrogates within a Unicode-encoded (whichever encoding!) string. UCS-2 (i.e. original Windows NT up to 2000) limited itself to the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) which amounted to 1 `wchar_t` == 1 *code point* (for Windows, elsewhere `wchar_t` differs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely a "wide character", `wchar_t[]` type.

These are always 16 bits long and they are used to allow international characters and symbols that are at most 16 bit long, that is, the UTF-16 range.

The fixed length allows faster processing than multibyte unicode.

ASCII characters that could be encoded as 1 byte in multibyte unicode take up 2 bytes in widechar, which "wastes" an extra byte that is always null.

Comment: Wait, what? That makes no sense, several aspects. The `wchar_t` in Windows is the *code unit* to _encode_ Unicode *code points*. And the full range of UTF-16 is very much supported. Yes, it has limitations compared to UTF-8 and UTF-32, but it _is very much a Unicode encoding_. UTF-16 has been used by Windows since XP (AFAIK) and previously UCS-2 was used, which can be considered sort of a predecessor to UTF-16. UCS-2 only ever considered the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) and thus limited itself to the notion of 1 `wchar_t` (16 bit) == 1 *code point*. Where the `\0` is depends on Endianess.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my answer. The null byte location depends on endianness, but the architectures Windows can run on are all little-endian.

Comment: these days, that is true. Agreed. But it wasn't always and UTF-16 (or Unicode in general) provides support for all of them. My main point was, however, that `wchar_t` is just the *code unit* and UTF-16 (since XP) does provide means to encode code points beyond a value range of 0..65535 through surrogates. So on modern Windows "characters" (code points) beyond the value 65535 are possible by encoding them via surrogate mechanism.